# Animate objects in Cocoa app OS X

Tags: cocoa, animation, core-animation, osx-mountain-lion

I'm looking to create simple animations (fades, windows sliding away, graphs moving or "filling up") in a Cocoa app I'm writing for OS X. I've tried finding information on Core Animation,  Core Graphics, NSViewAnimation, and Quartz Composer and how to use these in a Cocoa app, but I'm quickly losing direction. There was also one source saying that Core Animation was no longer supported as of MountainLion. What should be used for basic animations? Is there a specific framework or third-party library that will be useful, or a best-practice method for animating productivity apps?

I apologize for not being more specific, but I'm a bit confused on what exactly to look up.

Comment: Core Animation is still very much supported and is probably the framework you should be looking into. Where did you get that it wasn't supported from?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do is to modify the properties of your view's layers. To do that, you need to set the flag for your views that says "wants layer" (I work mostly in iOS these days, so I forget exactly what it's called.) When you do that for a view, that view and all it's subviews are backed with CALayer objects.

Changes to animatable properties of layers are animated "implicitly" by default. You can also enclose changes to a layer's properties inside a CATransaction begin/end block to change things like the layer timing and animation curve.

The next step up in complexity is to create CAAnimation objects and add them to your layer. Start with CABasicAnimation. You should be able to find tutorials on the net that show you how to animate layer properties using CABasicAnimations.

The documentation is pretty thin, I'm afraid.

iOS adds a set of view animation methods that make animating views very easy. Sadly, there is no equivalent on Mac OS. You have to deal with animation proxies, which is kind of confusing. There are a couple of Core Animation books you might look into. One is by [Marcus Zarra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321617754), and the other by [Bill Dudney](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356107).

EDIT: Another option I didn't mention in my (rather old) post: Mac OS view objects have something called an animation proxy. You can send property changes to a view's animation proxy and the system creates an animation that makes that change.

If you're using auto-layout, beware that changing a view's frame or bounds doesn't work as expected because auto-layout tries to take over size and placement of your view objects. Instead, you want to add outlets to your constraints and animate changes to the settings of the constraints.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This is a much better answer than what I've been getting. I think I understand what you're saying for the most part. I'll have to just try what I can to see how much carries over from iOS.